How to save array of key, value from json file? using prisma sqlite
I am unable to save customers, purchased items to my database, I am using sqlite prisma, belwo is my customers.json
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "firstName": "Emily",
    "lastName": "Davis",
    "username": "emilydavisxyz",
    "password": "password123",
    "role": "Customer",
    "balance": 1000,
      "street": "123 Main St",
      "city": "New York City",
      "country": "United States",
      "zipCode": "10001"
    
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "firstName": "Jane",
    "lastName": "Doe",
    "username": "janedoexyz",
    "password": "password123",
    "role": "Customer",
    "balance": 750,
    
      "street": "456 Elm St",
      "city": "London",
      "country": "United Kingdom",
      "zipCode": "32493"
    
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "firstName": "David",
    "lastName": "Brown",
    "username": "davidbrownxyz",
    "password": "password123",
    "role": "Customer",
    "balance": 500,
    
      "street": "789 Oak St",
      "city": "Sydney",
      "country": "Australia",
      "zipCode": "20200"
    
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "firstName": "Noah",
    "lastName": "Thomas",
    "username": "noahthomasxyz",
    "password": "password123",
    "role": "Customer",
    "balance": 1200,
   
      "street": "101 Pine St",
      "city": "Paris",
      "country": "France",
      "zipCode": "75001"
    
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "firstName": "Ava",
    "lastName": "Lee",
    "username": "avaleexyz",
    "password": "password123",
    "role": "Customer",
    "balance": 850,
    
      "street": "111 Cedar St",
      "city": "Tokyo",
      "country": "Japan",
      "zipCode": "45739"
    
  }
]

now this is my purchased-items.json
[
  {
    "purchaseId": 1,
    "userId": 1,
    "itemsPurchased": [
      {
        "isbn": "9780316769488",
        "quantity": 1,
        "imageUrl": "to_kill_a_mockingbird.jpg",
        "title": "To Kill a Mockingbird",
        "price": 10.99
      },
      {
        "isbn": "9781984818653",
        "quantity": 1,
        "imageUrl": "the_silent_patient.jpg",
        "title": "The Silent Patient",
        "price": 12.99
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "purchaseId": 2,
    "userId": 1,
    "itemsPurchased": [
      {
        "isbn": "9784012345678",
        "quantity": 3,
        "imageUrl": "whispers_in_the_attic.jpg",
        "title": "Whispers in the Attic",
        "price": 14.25
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "purchaseId": 3,
    "userId": 2,
    "itemsPurchased": [
      {
        "isbn": "9786021978321",
        "quantity": 2,
        "imageUrl": "atomic_habits.jpg",
        "title": "Atomic Habits",
        "price": 14.99
      },
      {
        "isbn": "9782753981642",
        "quantity": 1,
        "imageUrl": "the_power_of_meaning.jpg",
        "title": "The Power of Meaning",
        "price": 13.75
      },
      {
        "isbn": "9781982117801",
        "quantity": 1,
        "imageUrl": "educated.jpg",
        "title": "Educated",
        "price": 15.99
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "purchaseId": 4,
    "userId": 4,
    "itemsPurchased": [
      {
        "isbn": "9786021978321",
        "quantity": 3,
        "imageUrl": "atomic_habits.jpg",
        "title": "Atomic Habits",
        "price": 14.99
      },
      {
        "isbn": "9781984818653",
        "quantity": 2,
        "imageUrl": "the_silent_patient.jpg",
        "title": "The Silent Patient",
        "price": 12.99
      }
    ]
  }
]


This is the prisma schema I made: in schema.prisma client version
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "sqlite"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

model Books {
  id                Int     @id @default(autoincrement())
  isbn              String  @unique
  title             String
  author            String
  description       String
  genres            String
  publishedDate     String
  pageCount         Int
  imageUrl          String
  price             Float
  sales             Int
  availableQuantity Int
  sellerID          Int
  Sellers           Sellers @relation(fields: [sellerID], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade, onUpdate: Cascade)
}

model Sellers {
  id          Int     @id @default(autoincrement())
  firstName   String
  lastName    String
  username    String
  password    String
  role        String
  bankAccount String
  companyName String
  books       Books[] //books the seller is selling
}

model Customers {
  id            Int             @id @default(autoincrement())
  firstName     String
  lastName      String
  username      String
  password      String
  role          String
  balance       Int
  street        String
  city          String
  country       String
  zipCode       String
  purchaseditem purchasedItem[]
}

model purchasedItem {
  id     Int @id @default(autoincrement())
  userId Int

  itemsPurchased Item[]

  Customers   Customers? @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
  
}

model Item {
  isbn            String        @unique
  quantity        Int
  imageUrl        String
  title           String
  price           Float
  purchasedItemId Int           @unique
  purchasedItem   purchasedItem @relation(fields: [purchasedItemId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade, onUpdate: Cascade)
}


now finally this is how I am trying to seed in seed.js, but it is not working, what am i doing wrong how to fix?? please helpp
import fs from 'fs-extra'
import path from 'path'
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client'
const prisma = new PrismaClient()

const bookspath=path.join(process.cwd(),'app/data/books.json')
const sellerpath=path.join(process.cwd(),'app/data/sellers.json')
const customerpath=path.join(process.cwd(),'app/data/customers.json')
const purchasepath=path.join(process.cwd(),'app/data/purchased-items.json')


async function addBooks(b) {
    b.genres=b.genres.join(',');
    await prisma.books.create({data:b})
    //for retreiving as array use b.genres=b.genres.split(',')
}

async function savedata(itemsPurchased){
 try{
    const s=JSON.stringify(itemsPurchased);
    await prisma.purchasedItem.create({data:s});
    console.log("Data saved successfully")

 } catch(error){
    console.error('error saving data',error)
 }

}

async function main(){
 try{
    await prisma.books.deleteMany({});
    await prisma.sellers.deleteMany({});
    await prisma.customers.deleteMany({});
    await prisma.purchasedItem.deleteMany({});
    await prisma.item.deleteMany({});

    
    const seller=await fs.readJSON(sellerpath)
        for(const s of seller)
        await prisma.sellers.create({data:s})
    const book=await fs.readJSON(bookspath)
        for(const b of book)
            await addBooks(b) //this method will read according to data type
        const customer=await fs.readJSON(customerpath)
        for(const c of customer){
        await prisma.customers.create({data:c})

        const purchases=await fs.readJSON(purchasepath)
        for(let p of purchases){
            if(p.itemsPurchased){
                savedata(p.itemsPurchased)

            }
            else{

            }
            

        }
        
    }
        console.log("successfully seeded")
 }

 catch(error){
 console.log(error);
 }
}


await main()

I already added everything above, I want to save this data, so when i type npx prisma studio it shows me there properly, I don't know how to use postgressql thats why I want to use sqlite to implement this

Can you tell us what error(s) you get when you try to seed the database?
